# During the step script of gitlab Could not find or load main class sh after load docker image

Tags: java, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

`Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01 Using docker image sha256:75eb8c27787ee5c64311d798c9c0d2991a89024b516908 for gitlab-my_repo/maven3-jdk-8-git:V0.1 with digest gitlab-my_repo/maven3-jdk-8-git@sha256:febfe8e272bb8ccbb01116e7a177b979b53c080f11cafc ... Error: Could not find or load main class sh`

when i use CI_DEBUG_TRACE= true nothing else in the log..
For me it is a problem of classpath in java but why sh and not src/java/class.main...
Our gitlab runner work with docker Dind and the script of the custom image of maven3-jdk-8-git is :

`FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8 ENV TZ Europe/Paris ENV http_proxy XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX ENV https_proxy XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX RUN sed -i s/deb.debian.org/archive.debian.org/g /etc/apt/sources.list RUN sed -i 's|security.debian.org|archive.debian.org/|g' /etc/apt/sources.list RUN sed -i '/stretch-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list RUN echo "Install Git" && \ apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates apt-utils bzip2 git && \ rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/\* && \ \# Correction du maven pour supprimer le mirror bloquant line=$(grep -n maven-default-http-blocker /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml | awk -F: '{print           $1}') && \ echo sed -i -e "$((line - 1)),$((line+5))d" /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml COPY ./settings.xml /tmp/settings.xml ENTRYPOINT \["/usr/bin/java"\]`

I try this line in the dockerfile : `RUN java -classpath /bin/sh sh`
and i have the same error in the build of my dockerfile lol (Could not find or load main class sh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image includes `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]`, which is causing this problem. GitLab CI expects the images used for jobs to either have no `ENTRYPOINT` defined, or have a shell entrypoint.

You can either remove the entrypoint from the image or override it in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration:

```yaml
myjob:
  image: 
    name: my/custom/maven-image
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo "hello gitlab"
```